# How to create a shared library using gcc?

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I want to use pytwed package, but instruction says to produce a shared library loadable in python2 following:

```
gcc -std=c99 twed_wrap.c -lm -lpython2.7 -shared -o twed.so -fPIC -I /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ -I /usr/include/python2.7
```

I am doing it for the first time, so I am not able to understand the whole syntax, what it is doing and what all path it's asking about?

Can some one help?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which part don't you understand. Much of it is normal parameters to `gcc`.

Comment: i am creating a shared library for the first time, so i am not able to understand the whole syntax.

Comment: Most of it has nothing to do with creating a shared library. `-lm` is the same as normal compiling when you need to use the `libm` library. `-std=c99` means that it should compile according to the C99 standard. `-I` has the normal meaning of specifying where to find include files.

Comment: Do you know how to use GCC for compiling ordinary programs that aren't shared libraries?

Comment: In fact, the only part of this that's specific to creating a shared library is `-fPIC`.